# Laravel error: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\CityController::show()

Tags: laravel-5

So, this is my route.php code

```
Route::get('/city','CityController@index');
Route::get('/city/{id}','CityController@show');
```

This is my CityController.php

```
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use DB;
class CityController extends Controller{

public function index(){
    $cities = DB::table('city')->get();
    return view('homesite',compact('cities'));
}   
public function show($id){    //this line is having the eror
    $city = DB::table('city')->find($id);
    return view('citysite',compact('city'));
}
```

}
This is homesite.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('content')
@foreach($cities as $city)
<li><a href="city/{{$city->id}}">{{$city->cityName}}</a></li>   
@endforeach
@stop
```

This is citysite.blade.php

```
@extends('layout.master')
@section('content')
<h2>{{ $city->cityName }}</h2>
@stop
```

So, the error said that 
**Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\CityController::show()**, 
can anyone help me? Because I don't understand what's really wrong with my codes

Comment: when you go to the page and hover over the link, what does it say?

Comment: So, this is what the eror said ErrorException in CityController.php line 13: Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\CityController::show()  For more detail about the error: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fadx15caxuc8cp7/eror.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: As @PawelBieszczad says, it seems your link is not okay. Go hover the link, what does it say? Does it show something like http://host/city/a_numer?

Comment: So, before I click the link, it is 'localhost/ins-laravel1/public/city' After I hover the link, it is 'localhost/ins-laravel1/public/city/1'

Comment: First thing, your web server config is not right. You must set the public folder as your apache root folder (assuming you are using Apache).

Answer (score 0):

When we calling a function like show($id) it means that it(the show function) receives a data from the calling page.

I believe that the issue might be with the way you load the page.